# Copying data from one spreadsheet to another Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am stuck on getting anything to copy from a closed Google Sheet to an open one.
This is my attempted script which the debugger does not get past line 2:

```
function lloydsRestore() {
    var ss =SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ZRHHA1fcXXCXwD4nCjjtIg67DHvtm5pLjmwzJiD3ZgA").getActiveSheet();
    var ls = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Lloyds');
    var values= ls.setActiveSelection("A1:T72").getvalues;

    var bs = App.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BS');
    var bsput = bs.getRange("A1:T72").setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: What error does the debugger show?  What is `ss` used for?  You define it in line 2, but never use it.  Which sheet is "closed" and which is "open"?

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there - just a few misunderstandings in your script.

You are opening the sheet (ss) so you use ss.getSheetByName(...) rather than SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName(...)

You aren't calling getValues correctly - you need the ()

```
function lloydsRestore() {

    var ss =SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ZRHHA1fcXXCXwD4nCjjtIg67DHvtm5pLjmwzJiD3ZgA');
    var ls = ss.getSheetByName('Lloyds');
    var values = ls.getRange('A1:T72').getValues();

    var bs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BS');
    var bsput = bs.getRange('A1:T72').setValues(values);
}
```

You may not need a script for this however as the [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) function does exactly what your function does. Put the following in a cell and you will get your values imported.

=IMPORTRANGE('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZRHHA1fcXXCXwD4nCjjtIg67DHvtm5pLjmwzJiD3ZgA', 'Lloyds!A1:T72')

Comment: Now I understand!   I had avoided the importrange method as I wanted to include dependent choice through a menu but on thinking about it i could make the import very dependent by including it in If()'s